# Linked list implementation of a struct of students

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list of student with the struct below.

```
struct student 
{
    int student_ID;
    char *student_name;
    struct course *courses_enrolled;
    Student *child;
};

//Insert student to the list with a given student pointer and the starting point
Student *insert_student(Student *child, Student *root)
{
    Student *temp = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    //if there isn't a starting point, declare this as the start point
    if( root->student_name == NULL )
    {
        root->student_ID = child->student_ID;
        root->student_name = strdup(child->student_name;);
        root->child = NULL;
    }
    //if this student's name is before current node, replace node.
    else if( strcmp( child->student_name, root->student_name ) < 0 )
    {
        temp = root;
        root = child;
        child->child = temp;
    }
    //if this student's name is after current node, keep doing insert recursion
    else if( strcmp( child->student_name, root->student_name ) > 0 )
    {
        insert_student( child, root->child );
    }

    return root;
}
```

The first root insertion would always work fine but when I attempt to add the 2nd one, the program will seg fault after the 2nd call to insert_student. It fails at the comparison

```
if( root->student_name == NULL )
```

I suspect that is has something to do with me accessing the child node of the root (root->child) but i'm not really sure what.

p/s: I know I'm not deallocating, that's just a temporary thing as I'm required to use a different library.

UPDATE: Removed excess code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to find the exact problem for we are not given how this function is called. There seems to be a few things that you want to check.

I am assuming that the `child` and `root` that you passed in to the function are indeed allocated, with all fields in root set to `NULL` and that student's name are in order so that your second branch never happen. Then, the first insertion will work.

But, when you do the second insertion. You are passing in `root->child` which you have set to `NULL` in the first `if` clause. This will led subsequent `strcmp` to fail, because you cannot dereference from `NULL` (e.g. `NULL->student_name` throws an error).

Answer (score 0):

When you recursively call insert_student you should make sure the value you're passing as `root` is not null. You probably need another case for if it is null (like inserting on the end).

One thing I noticed is that you never use the allocated value of `temp`. It is always unused or thrown away before `temp` is used. I'm assuming this is not what you want.

Also, generally the word `next` would be used instead of `child` in the struct and something like `newStudent` or just `student` instead of child in the parameter.

Comment: yeah, you're right about it not failing at that part, I've recheck and I believe that it is actually failing at the comparison (edited my post to reflect that). I also removed the temp allocation, it was suppose to be for something else that I removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( root->student_name == NULL )
{
    printf("Always here?\n");
    root->student_ID = child->student_ID;
    root->student_name = strdup(child->student_name);
    temp->student_ID = 0;
    temp->student_name = NULL;
    root->child = temp;
}
```

I found out that I actually need to declare the variables of the child node to be NULL before I can access them.